# How do I automatically close alertview in Swift?

Tags: swift, alert

I use [this](https://github.com/codestergit/SweetAlert-iOS) and [this](https://github.com/stakes/JSSAlertView) functions on my swift project. However, I want to close the alerts programmatically. How do I do this?

Comment: Please provide a lot more context, I will not visit your links, include the necessary code, the current behavior, what exactly you want to achieve, what you have tried so far and in what way your solutions is not yet working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this method to close SweetAlert

**Usage:**

```
sweetAlert.closeAlert(0)
```